# Field replacement pattern not rendering

Tags: views, 8

I am running Drupal 8.7.8

I've created a view and excluded my fields from display except for the last field for which I have rewritten the results to output all the replacement strings in a certain layout. Everything works fine except for the videos.

I have two videos {{ field_video }} and {{ field_youtube }}. Both replacement patterns do not render to the screen.

Any fixes for how to render them when rewriting the results of fields?

Comment: Are these listed in the re-write results replacement pattern suggestions?

Comment: Yes. I have the field at the bottom of the list for the rewrite. The replacement pattern is showing the replacement strings. I have 2 fields one for youtube and one for a regular mp4. One of them shows blank, and the other one shows a link to the video and not a video itself.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You could try creating a template file for your view's fields and printing them there rather than re-write results.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. Lots of bugs and unavailable modules in Drupal 8 honestly...